# How to trim and clean the cell in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a code which takes the  column name as input from the user and then adds a column with the same column name at the end of the sheet. The problem I am facing is that my code does not execute the lines which I have typed in to trim and clean the newly added column name

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

LastColumn = sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
'MsgBox LastColumn

ColumnName = InputBox("Name of column to be added")
'MsgBox ColumnName

sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = ColumnName

MsgBox sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value

Trim (sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value)
sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1))
UCase (sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the result after the `Trim()` either in a variable,

```
Dim variableText As String

variableText = Trim(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value)
variableText = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1))
variableText = UCase(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value)
```

or in the cell itself:

```
sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = Trim(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value)
sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1))
sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = UCase(sht.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value)
```

Comment: No problem. Normally there is no need for saying thanks, just mark the answer as accepted, thats enough. This way other viewers know which answer worked for the poster.